# Optimization non-linear constraints over parameters

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I'm trying to optimize the following:

min y - (b1*x1 - b2*x2 + b3x3)

subject to: b1 + b2b3^2 < 1

y and x's are known data. And b1, b2 and b3 the parameters to be found.

It is similar to MLE problems, but I failed to find a package that allow me to introduce the constraint.
NclOptim is a good option but I couldn't find examples when you have data (y and x's).

Finally, I hope to find a solution even if the objective function is linear or non-linear (in the parameters or data).

Comment: I would try a general-purpose NLP solver (one that allows constraints).

Comment: Thank you... but what r packages could I use?

Comment: `nloptr` supports a number of algorithms.